# Can't use hover with jQuery Tag Cloud

Tags: jquery, tag-cloud

I need to add an onHover event when people hover over any of the items inside the tag cloud, here's the code.. I think there's a conflict somewhere. Right now it does not trigger at all.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQCloud Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jqcloud/jqcloud.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqcloud/jqcloud-1.0.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var word_list = [
                {text: "Lorem", weight: 13, link: "https://github.com/DukeLeNoir/jQCloud"},
                {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5, html: {title: "My Title", "class": "custom-class"}, link: {href: "http://jquery.com/", target: "_blank"}},
                {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4},
                {text: "Sit", weight: 8},
                {text: "Amet", weight: 6.2},
                {text: "Consectetur", weight: 5},
                {text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5},
                {text: "Elit", weight: 5},
                {text: "Nam et", weight: 5},
                {text: "Leo", weight: 4},
                {text: "Sapien", weight: 4},
                {text: "Pellentesque", weight: 3},
                {text: "habitant", weight: 3},
                {text: "morbi", weight: 3},
                {text: "tristisque", weight: 3},
                {text: "senectus", weight: 3},
                {text: "et netus", weight: 3},
                {text: "et malesuada", weight: 3},
                {text: "fames", weight: 2},
                {text: "ac turpis", weight: 2},
                {text: "egestas", weight: 2},
                {text: "Aenean", weight: 2},
                {text: "vestibulum", weight: 2},
                {text: "elit", weight: 2},
                {text: "sit amet", weight: 2},
                {text: "metus", weight: 2},
                {text: "adipiscing", weight: 2},
                {text: "ut ultrices", weight: 2},
                {text: "justo", weight: 1},
                {text: "dictum", weight: 1},
                {text: "Ut et leo", weight: 1},
                {text: "metus", weight: 1},
                {text: "at molestie", weight: 1},
                {text: "purus", weight: 1},
                {text: "Curabitur", weight: 1},
                {text: "diam", weight: 1},
                {text: "dui", weight: 1},
                {text: "ullamcorper", weight: 1},
                {text: "id vuluptate ut", weight: 1},
                {text: "mattis", weight: 1},
                {text: "et nulla", weight: 1},
                {text: "Sed", weight: 1}
            ];
            $(function() {
                $("#my_favorite_latin_words").jQCloud(word_list);
                $('span').hover(function() {
                    alert('a');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>jQCloud Example</h1>
        <div id="my_favorite_latin_words" style="width: 550px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jqcloud's `afterCloudRender` to run you jquery after jqcloud is done making your wordcloud

```
$('#example').jQCloud(words,{
    shape : 'rectangle',
    afterCloudRender : function(){
        $('span','#example').each(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

The `hover` handler is being bound to `span` elements that don't yet exist on page load. As a result, the handler is not bound to the dynamically added `span` elements.

**Solution**

Instead of *binding* the handler function directly, you should *delegate* it higher up the DOM to a parent element that exists on page load.

For example:

```
$("#my_favorite_latin_words").on('mouseenter', 'span', function() {
    alert('a');
});
```